# Tensorflow2.0a: Why is keras.models.load_model() slower than model.from_config()?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have built a couple of custom layers and model in Tensorflow2.0a extending the Keras classes. In all of them I have implement the `get_config()` and `from_config()` methods. I have also implemented a `model.save()` method in the CustomModel class (similarly to the Sequential model).

```py
def save(self, filepath, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True, **kwargs):
        from tensorflow.python.keras.models import save_model  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
        save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
```

Those methods allow me to use:

```py
model.save("model.h5")
new_model = keras.models.load_model('model.h5',
                                    custom_objects={
                'CustomModel': CustomModel,
                'CustomLayer': CustomLayer, #...
})
```

This takes around 30sec to load a model with 8 layers and 9000 parameters.

But I can also load the model this way:

```py
model.save_weights("weights.h5")
config = model.get_config()
new_model = CustomModel.from_config(config)
new_model.load_weights("weights.h5")
```

This method on the other hand takes 0.6sec for the same model.

Is there a reason why the first method is so slow ? Is it due to the deserialisation of the custom model/layers ?

In that case what should be the preferred method ?

I am aware TF2 is quite new, but any insight would be greatly appreciated!